# "ctl00_Body" in asp.net generated objects' id

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, .net

I'm using asp.net with c# and I'm using the normal asp.net controllers (asp:Table, asp:Button, etc), but I need to use some javascript over these controllers and even though I set up the id like:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

in the html code I get

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$Body$Button1" value="Button" id="ctl00_Body_Button1" />
```

where the ID changed from "Button1" to "ctl00_Body_Button1". Is there I can get the "ct_100_Body_" in javascript so I can access the controller by ID properly, and to avoid typing something like

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_Body_Button1")
```

for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this behavior use following ClientIDMode="Static" at very top of your web page, see example

```
<%@ Page Title="Configuration" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageBootstrap.master"
    CodeFile="Dashboard.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dashboard" ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

you can use this at page level or control level, you can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

this way you can use `document.getElementById("Button1")`

Comment: Thank you! The ClientIDMode="Static" was the whole deal! Thanks!